# Pine Script : Open Session Not Appearing Saturday and Sunday

Tags: session, range, pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I am coding an 'Open Session' indicator in TradingView.
I don't know why the ranges do not show up on Saturday an Sunday.

Can someone tell where is the problem please ?

````
showHi = input(true, "Show highs")
showLo = input(true, "Show lows")

open_ranges_D1  = "D"

opd1_session_input       = input("2200-2000", type=input.session)
asia_session_input       = input("0000-2300", type=input.session)
fkft_session_input       = input("0700-2300", type=input.session)
nyse_session_input       = input("1330-2300", type=input.session)

// |--------------|
// | OPD1 SESSION |
// |--------------|
opd1_clr_D1 = color(#00ff0a)
// Check to see if we are in allowed hours.
opd1_newbar_opr_D1 = time(open_ranges_D1, opd1_session_input)
var float opd1_hi = 0
var float opd1_lo = 0
if opd1_newbar_opr_D1
    // We are entering allowed hours; reset opd1_hi/opd1_lo.
    if not opd1_newbar_opr_D1[1]
        opd1_hi := high
        opd1_lo := low
    else
        // We are in allowed hours; track opd1_hi/opd1_lo.
        opd1_hi := max(opd1_hi, opd1_hi)   // originially : opd1_hi := max(srcHi, opd1_hi)
        opd1_lo := min(opd1_lo, opd1_lo)   //               opd1_lo := min(srcLo, opd1_lo)

opd1_hi_plot = plot(showHi and not(noPlotOutside and not opd1_newbar_opr_D1)? opd1_hi : na, title="opd1_hi_D1", color=opd1_clr_D1, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr, transp=50)
opd1_lo_plot = plot(showLo and not(noPlotOutside and not opd1_newbar_opr_D1)? opd1_lo : na, title="opd1_lo_D1", color=opd1_clr_D1, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr, transp=50)

fill(opd1_hi_plot, opd1_lo_plot, color=opd1_clr_D1, transp=80) ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a session to `time()`, you can also specify the relevant days of week. The format looks like this: `"0000-0000:1234567"`, days of week start from Sunday. The default days are Mon-Fri `":23456"`, which is why your script doesn't work on Saturdays and Sundays.

This should help:

```
opd1_newbar_opr_D1 = time(open_ranges_D1, opd1_session_input + ":1234567")
```